# Wordpress custom post type not displaying on front page when 'has archive' is set to true

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

I have 3 post types on my site. 2 are custom post types. I created 3 separate loops on the main index page and I query the 2 custom posts using this code

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
```

I'm using Custom Post Types UI plugin but when I change the 'has archive' option to true, one of my custom post types disappears from the main index page. So say the code for custom post type 'events' is first and the code for 'books' is underneath, the books custom post type just disappears, however if I change the 'has archive' option to false, the custom post reappears

Answer (score 0):

From Wordpress Codex.

> query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main
>   query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is
>   inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some
>   circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).
>   Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use
>   of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

Here is a good article which can help you out.

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page